# ObservableQuery for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

Using `ObservableCollection`s with Silverlight works great, because the UI is automatically updated when the data changes. But what if I am displaying a whole number of different views of the data, represented as different `IEnumerable` LINQ queries? My current approach is to have the `DataContext` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and register for the backing collections `CollectionChanged` event, and fire the property changed event accordingly.

However, this is sort of repetitive to do over and over again. What I really want is an `ObservableQuery` that combines a query and an observable data source. Does this exist already? If not, what do I need to do when rolling my own for Silverlight to treat it the same way as an `ObservableCollection`? Is having a `CollectionChanged` event sufficient?

(I am most interested in Silverlight for the Windows Phone 7.)

Answer (score 1):

What you describe doesn't really exist as such, but if you pass your `IEnumerable<xx>` into a `CollectionViewSource` (edit) you can get a few of the features decribed. This how ever does not fit so well with a ViewModel type pattern since you have to pull some leavers manually to make it work.

Another option is to take a quick look at the **[Reactive Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/).** It's currently CTP (or maybe beta), but is also implemented for SilverLight. This gives you a LINQ querieable, `IObservable<xx>` Observable Stream or Collection (not to be confused with the `ObservableCollection`), that is basically an asynchronous, "push" version of `IEnumerable` .

It works very well with slow data loading into UI over a long period of time. You can can e.g. convert events into an observable stream, and start your LINQ query from there ect..

Check out this exellent Ch9 video w. Wes Dyer explaining how to use it with UI:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/J.Van.Gogh/Writing-your-first-Rx-Application